# Pyinstaller .exe file giving me "no module found cryptography" error in the console

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, python-cryptography, auto-py-to-exe

I wrote one program in python on my Linux virtual machine, and converted it to .exe using pyinstaller, but the console on my windows VM gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python file.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
[2224] Failed to execute script 'python file' due to unhandled exception
```

I usually always solve such problems myself, but here I’ve just been suffering with this program for 3 months and I can’t make out this problem.

in pyinstaller (autopytoexe) i have this command to convert my .py to exe

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "cryptography" "C:/Users/user/Desktop/python file.py"
```

Other users on the internet they write that

```
--hidden-import "cryptography"
```

should have solved the problem, but that didn't help either.

and in the python code, I also wrote this at the start of the file

```
import os
import cryptography
import cryptography.fernet
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code and errors, instead copy them in the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about directly copy from your environment?
first, dont use onefile option. And copy the 'cryptography' folder from your python environment to your dist folder.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by doing `pip install cryptography`.